# Spring:message in android

Tags: android, spring

I am studying Java EE and Spring for web development.

Suddenly, my manager told me to create multi language functionality in android.
I know how to do it in Java EE but I don't know how to do it in Android.

Do you have any suggestions? Can i use spring on android or do I have to use other frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android already supports multi language texts, so you do not need another Framework for that.
Here is the link with all the information: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

You cannot use the Spring Framework for this as it is not a Web-Framework, not an Android-Framework. There is Spring for Android but that only gives you this functionality:

- A Rest Client for Android
- Auth support for accessing secure APIs